# Maven multiple definitions in dependencyManagement - especially with import

Tags: java, maven, import, dependencies, dependency-management

How does Maven handle multiple definitions of a dependency in the dependencyManagement section of pom.xml? e.g.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <!-- Exclusion needed to prevent conflicts with SLF4j -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Here I've defined spring-context twice. Once with an exclusion and once without. Maven runs and builds with both entries present. But I'm not certain how it 'reads' the dependency. Sensible behavior may be for it to merge the definitions. Though I'm not sure that's possible. Failing that I'd expect it to print an error.

While the above is not clear to me it becomes more complex if there is an import scope definition.

e.g.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

What happens here if a dependency is defined in both the importing and spring-boot-dependencies pom.xml?

Comment: Take a look at this http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html

Comment: Handy utility for experimentation. Would love to get some documentation defining what I see. Namely - with duplicate dependencies the last definition is used. There is no merge. e.g. Above the spring-context with the exclusion is used. For the 'import' scope order does not matter. If it's defined in the importing pom.xml that's the version that's used.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the last entry wins and child poms overwrite parent poms. But imports are handled differently - they are not on the "same level" as other dependenyManagement entries. For details, see

[dependencyManagement - imports and direct entries in parent poms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339668/dependencymanagement-imports-and-direct-entries-in-parent-poms)

Comment: is this explained anywhere in the Maven documentation?